# Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application tries to save when I just want slideshow to play

Tags: c#, .net, com, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm running the following code to open a PowerPoint file from a WPF app. The file opens, but after clicking through the slideshow I'm prompted something along the lines of, "We can't save the slideshow because it is read-only" - even though the file is not set as read-only, and also I didn't want to save it - just play it. Does anybody have any insight so I can play it without attempting to save it?

> Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application pptApp = new
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.PoIwerPoint.Presentation presentation =
>   pptApp.Presentations.Open2007(fileName, 
>   Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
>   Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 
>                              Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
>                           Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowSettings sst =
>   presentation.SlideShowSettings;
>                           sst.ShowType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideShowType.ppShowTypeSpeaker;
>                           sst.Run();

Comment: I have no idea why you are prompted to save the presentation, but as a workaround try setting `presentation.Saved = msoTrue` after the `Run` statement.

Comment: Thank you! That works as a fix.

Comment: As to why you're getting the request to save, SlideShowSettings are stored in the file. Because you changed them, PowerPoint sees the file as changed, so will ask if you want to save.